# How can i close a python file which is converted to the .exe?

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I've used **pyinstaller** to convert my python file to the **.exe** file.But I don't know how to close that.I've searched for it and I couldn't find what I was looking for.I used this line to convert my **main.py** file to the **.exe**

```
pyinstaller --onefile -w main.py
```

How can i close **main.exe**  which is running currently?

[My python files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9idy.png)

Edit:
I tried to delete this file but windows said 'it's running so you can't delete it until you close it'

Comment: Can't you press the x button or use task manager? An exe should run like any program on your computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can kill the task in task manager or simply restart your computer

For the future run of your code, you can remove the `-w` from the pyinstaller argument so the terminal will show up.